# Get second element text with XPath?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

```
<span class='python'>
  <a>google</a>
  <a>chrome</a>
</span>
```

I want to get `chrome` and have it working like this already.

```
q = item.findall('.//span[@class="python"]//a')
t = q[1].text # first element = 0
```

I'd like to combine it into a single XPath expression and just get one item instead of a list.
I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
t = item.findtext('.//span[@class="python"]//a[2]') # first element = 1
```

And the actual, not simplified, HTML is like this.

```
<span class='python'>
  <span>
    <span>
      <img></img>
      <a>google</a>
    </span>
    <a>chrome</a>
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Your expression `.//span[@class="python"]//a[2]` works for me.

Comment: Hmmm it seems I have a mistake somewhere, or the simplification of the actual HTML I posted is _too_ simple. I'll try and then modify the question.

Comment: @pdnsk: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation and for a simple solution. :)

Comment: so glad you posted this question. Been trying to figure out a similar problem for about a day.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> I tried this but it doesn't work.
>
> ```
> t = item.findtext('.//span[@class="python"]//a[2]')
> ```

**This is a FAQ about the `//` abbreviation**.

`.//a[2]` means: Select all `a` descendents of the current node that are the second `a` child of their parent. So this may select more than one element or no element -- depending on the concrete XML document.

To put it more simply, the `[]` operator has higher precedence than `//`.

If you want just one (the second) of all nodes returned you have to use brackets to force your wanted precedence:

`(.//a)[2]`

This really selects the second `a` descendent of the current node.

**For the actual expression used in the question, change it to**:

```
(.//span[@class="python"]//a)[2]
```

or change it to:

```
(.//span[@class="python"]//a)[2]/text()
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I have one question, or actually two. If there is only one matching element, will `[2]` throw an exception or return `None`? And do you know why this works with `xpath` but not `findtext`?

Comment: @pdnsk: My answer is pure XPath. I don't know Python.

Comment: I tried and it just returns no element, which is good because one reason why I wanted to avoid lists and have it in a single expression is to not have an additional check.

Comment: Been trying to figure out a similar answer for a full day. Thanks a ton for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the problem is...

```
>>> d = """<span class='python'>
...   <a>google</a>
...   <a>chrome</a>
... </span>"""
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> d = etree.HTML(d)
>>> d.xpath('.//span[@class="python"]/a[2]/text()')
['chrome']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

**From Comments:**

> or the simplification of the actual
>   HTML I posted is too simple

You are right. What is the meaning of `.//span[@class="python"]//a[2]`? This will be expanded to:

```
self::node()
 /descendant-or-self::node()
  /child::span[attribute::class="python"]
   /descendant-or-self::node()
    /child::a[position()=2]
```

It will finaly select the second `a` child (`fn:position()` refers to the `child` axe). So, nothing will be select if your document is like:

```
<span class='python'> 
  <span> 
    <span> 
      <img></img> 
      <a>google</a><!-- This is the first "a" child of its parent --> 
    </span> 
    <a>chrome</a><!-- This is also the first "a" child of its parent --> 
  </span> 
</span>
```

If you want the second of all descendants, use:

```
descendant::span[@class="python"]/descendant::a[2]
```

Comment: It works with `xpath` but not with `findtext`, and returns a list with one item.

Comment: @pdknsk: That's because this XPath expression return a node set result: it could be empty, it could be a singleton, it could be many spans with a "python" class an a second descendant... If you want the **string value** of the first of this results, use `string()` function with this expression as argument. I don't know what kind of data type can return your `xpath` method...

Comment: It works. I used a combination of the previous answer, with `/text()`,  and this answer, but I'll accept this answer because it details the problem. I only have one question. What is the short equivalent to `/descandant::`?

Comment: @pdknsk: First, `text()` will return all the text node children. `string()` or the DOM method for string value will return the concatenation of all descendant text nodes. **It's not the same**. Second, there is no abbreviated form for `descendant` axe. My last expression it's equivalent to `(.//span[@class="python"]//a)[2]?` so the `position()` predicate gets applied to the whole expression not just last step.