# XPath Without Selector

Tags: xpath

Suppose I have following code:

```
<div class="Class">
<h3>First Title H3</h3>
    First Description <br />
    Choose Option:
    <select id="Id" name="Name">
       <option value="Value1">Option1 $Price1</option>
       <option value="Value2">Option2 $Price2</option>
       <option value="Value3">Option3 $Price3</option>
    </select>
<h3>Second Title H3</h3>
    Second Description <a href="https://www.example.com/">Link</a>
</div>
```

- What's the Xpath to print "First Description" only?
- What's the XPath to print "$Price1" **only** (without/exclude "Option1")?
  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is your desired output, but here is what should help you.

`following-sibling::text()` would help you to check the `First Description`:

```
//div/h3[contains(following-sibling::text(), "First Description")]
```

For the first `option` of the `select` tag, I would rely on the `select`'s `id` attribute and `option`'s `value` attribute:

```
//select[@id="Id"]/option[@value="Value1"]/text()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, alecxe. I will try it. Sorry for my English language, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved based on this answers: [using XPath: how to exclude text in nested elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218264/using-xpath-how-to-exclude-text-in-nested-elements) and [XPath: select text node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033955/xpath-select-text-node) and [Get second element text with XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117953/get-second-element-text-with-xpath)

Answer (score 0):

String value = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@value ='Value1']").getText();

String strarr[] = value.split(" ");

System.out.println("Price1 :"+ strarr[1]);

I think this will work, we are finding the text and splitting with space.